# How to have a discord bot read out a cell from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, discord

Consider me a beginner.
I have created a discord bot which is connected to my own test server, written in Python. If it's simpler to do so, I can switch to java language, as I just picked up Python.
I have very basic knowledge of Google App-script
I have not yet authorize my Discord bot to see my spreadsheet, as I do not know how to authorize such.

Currently, I have a spreadsheet filled with numbers and data that I want the discord bot to read and post it as a message in Discord channel.

For simplicity, suppose there is a "Sheet1" sheet and within it, cell B3 has a text "Send me away". I want the Discord Bot to look at my spreadsheet at that cell B3, check if the cell is not empty and if so, copy it, and then post it as a message in a discord channel. It will perform this task with a discord command (the command name would be ?SendMe).

How can I perform such task?

Comment: Show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Comment: It hurts out, it's much more of a headache than I thought

I have authorized and given the discord bot credentials and is now able to read out the cell from the spreadsheet
though, I am having big issue as to how to have the google app script tell the bot to message in a channel. Typically, you take information from other websites and input it into the spreadsheet, but I wanted the spreadsheet to send a message in a discord chat. How could I accomplish this>

Comment: Please [edit] this question or delete it and post a new one.